# Can $bab$ be a generator of the following covering space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, free-groups

In the following covering space, can $bab$ be a generator of a covering space of $S^1\vee S^1$? Is it more natural to let $bab$ as the generator instead of $bab^{-1}$ as pointed out by Hatcher in his book Algebraic Topology page 58?

[image]

The $b^{-1}$ means the reverse path taken in the opposite direction of $b$ right? Why can't we use the other path $b$ above of the first $b$?

Could someone please help me clarify the confusion? Thanks.

Comment: The general technique Hatcher is using here is to write one sequence of generators that "lassos" each single loop in the space. You can do this however you want, then freely multiply generators together to get a cleaner presentation.

Conversely, if the graph has $n$ distinct 2-cells, $n$ independent generators in the resulting presentation should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it feels more natural to include $bab$ since it helps you cover the entire graph, but there is a much simpler reason to include $bab^{-1}$ instead. The reason is that $bab$ wraps around both circles, while $bab^{-1}$ wraps around only one circle, so altogether the generators in $\langle a, b^2, bab^{-1}\rangle$ each wrap around one distinct circle.

Note that $bab^{-1}b^2 = bab$, so  both presentations are technically equivalent.